# Startup script for a Next.js app using Phusion Passenger (starting the production build using a file)?

Tags: node.js, next.js, passenger

Usually a Next.js app is started using `npm run start` after building it with `npm run build`. I can't start it with a command because my web server stack (Phusion Passenger) **requires a startup script**.

[image: Phusion Passenger]

**What I've tested so far**:

- Startup file: `node_modules/.bin/next`: it does't work (JavaScript error), I think because the default behavior is to start Next in develop mode
- A startup script as [suggested here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17289):

```
const path = require('path');

const nextPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'next');

process.argv.length = 1;
process.argv.push(nextPath, 'start');

require(nextPath);
```

But I receive an error from the web server: "Incomplete response received from application". From the logs (app has been build correctly with `next build`):

> App 9526 output: ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
> App 9526 output: Error: Could not find a production build in the '/var/www/vhosts/XXX/nextjs/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/production-start-no-build-id

Comment: Did u find any solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Try using the offical script provided by next.js docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server).

I'm using `node v14` and `npm 6.14.15`

```
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
    // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
```

I pointed `pessenager` to the `server.js` file and build my assets with `/opt/plesk/node/14/bin/npm run build --scripts-prepend-node-path`